# How to change the innertext of an <a> tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

Considering the following code:

```
<li><a href="#" id="vm1">LA1</a></li>
```

It is in an html file and its innertext is LA1 as is shown above. Now I want to change the value of the innertext of the above  tag through the following code:

```
document.getElementById("vm1").innerHTML= "LA2";
```

It didn't work. I thought that it might be the browser I am utilizing (chrome) does not support innerHTML. So I tried an another way:

```
document.getElementById("vm1").innerText = "LA2"
```

It did not work either. So what should I to to set the innertext of an  tag through js.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me using innerText.. https://jsfiddle.net/Lkam6L70/

Comment: I think that you problem is not here. You should show real code.

Comment: You can do exactly what you've done in the first snippet. Make sure `#vm1` exists before you refer it.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/avf2mose/

Comment: I have a feeling you are running your javascript before your html is loaded

Answer (score 1):

The issue is more than likely that your script is running before you html is running, and if this is the case you should either move the code after the html or add an eventlistener that listens for when the dom has loaded like this:

### Option 1 - Move code below html

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" id="vm1"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("vm1").innerText = "LA2";
  </script>
</body>
```

---

### Option 2 - Wrap code in an DOMContentLoaded listener

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.getElementById("vm1").innerText = "LA2";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code that manipulate your content like this. I suspect you are trying this before you anchor is loaded?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("vm1").innerText = 'works!'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#vm1').text('la2');
```

Should work

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on this question

Comment: I dont't see that Tim is using jQuery.